# Make one Docker Compose service know the domain name of another

Tags: networking, docker, dns, docker-compose, hosts-file

I'm using Docker Compose to create two containers. One runs an Nginx web server which serves the `mydomain.com` website, and the second needs to send HTTP requests to the first one (using the `mydomain.com` domain name).

I don't want to have to check the Nginx container's ip each time I run it  and then use `docker run --add-host` on the second container. My goal is to run `docker-compose up` and that everything be ready.

I know it's not possible, but what I'm looking for is something in the line of:

```
# docker-compose.yml
nginx_container:
    ...

second_container:
    extra_hosts:
         # This is invalid. extra_hosts only accepts ips.
        - "mydomain.com:nginx_container"
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel.   Linked containers for the win.

Comment: My containers are already linked. Could you give more details about how this alone should solve my problem?

Comment: Fire up your nginx standalone, then try:

     docker run -it --rm --link <nginxcontainername>:www.test.com alpine /bin/ash

Once inside you can ping www.test.com just fine.    And see how it is linked by inspecting /etc/hosts.

Comment: Don't use old wheels ;) Use Docker Networking, not links -https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 3):

You can get a similar result using a configuration like this:

```
version: "3"

services:    
  api:
    image: node:8.9.3
    container_name: foo_api
    domainname: api.foo.test
    command: 'npm run dev'
    links:
      - "mongo:mongo.foo.test"
      - "redis:redis.foo.test"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: redis:3
    container_name: foo_redis
    domainname: redis.foo.test
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.2
    container_name: foo_mongo
    domainname: mongo.foo.test
    ports:
      - "${MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT}
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```