# Can't fetch user info from Keycloak using Python on docker compose

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I need to run, from docker compose, three containers: a fastapi server, a keycloack server and a postgres database.
This works well if I run the uvicorn command from my local bash instead of from docker-compose service. I also noted that if I run the code from outside docker-compose, I get the authorization option `OpenIdConnect (OAuth2, authorization_code)` and from docker-compose: `OpenIdConnect (OAuth2, authorization_code with PKCE)`.

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    web:
        build: ./foo
        command: uvicorn main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
        volumes:
            - ./foo:/usr/src
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
            - kc
        environment:
            BAR_ENV: local
            LOGGER_NAME: local
            BAR_DB_LOCAL_USERPASS: bar:bar
            BAR_DB_LOCAL_DB_NAME: bar
            BAR_DB_LOCAL_HOST: localhost:5438
            BAR_HOSTNAME: bar.local
            BAR_AUTH_URL: http://auth.bar.local:8087
            BAR_FRONT_URL: bar.local:3000
    kc:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak-x:latest
        command: start-dev --db=postgres --db-url-host=$$DB_HOST --db-url-database=$$DB_DATABASE --db-username=$$DB_USER --db-password=$$DB_PASS --http-port=8087
        environment:
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
            DB_HOST: db
            DB_DATABASE: &KC_DB_DB keycloak
            DB_USER: &KC_DB_USER keycloak
            DB_PASS: &KC_DB_PASS keycloak
        domainname: auth.bar.local
        ports:
            - 8087:8087
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./resources/keycloak-themes:/opt/keycloak/themes/theme
    db:
        image: postgres:14
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            KC_DB_DB: *KC_DB_DB
            KC_DB_USER: *KC_DB_USER
            KC_DB_PASS: *KC_DB_PASS
            BAR_DB_DB: bar
            BAR_DB_USER: bar
            BAR_DB_PASS: bar
        ports:
            - 5438:5432
        volumes:
            - ./data/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./resources/init-kc-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-kc-db.sh
            - ./resources/init-bar-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-bar-db.sh
```

I'm able to access `http://<realm>.bar.local:8000/docs` from the browser and to authenticate on `OpenIdConnect (OAuth2, authorization_code with PKCE)`. It redirects me to keycloak login page and, then, back to swagger. But, if I try one of my endpoints in swagger, for example, `/whoami`, I get a 500 internal server error.

Logs from `web_1` service:

```
web_1      | keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakConnectionError: Can't connect to server (HTTPConnectionPool(host='auth.bar.local', port=8087): Max retries exceeded with url: /realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd38041a6b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
web_1      | {"asctime": "2022-04-26 11:31:54,929", "threadName": "MainThread", "filename": "httptools_impl.py", "lineno": 437, "message": "172.18.0.1:63454 - \"GET /api/v1_0/whoami HTTP/1.1\" 500", "severity": "INFO"}
```

the error above occurs in my keycloak_auth.py, when it tries to fetch user info from `self.kc_clients[org]`:

```
class OpenIdConnectMultipleViaKeycloak(SecurityBase):

    def __init__(
            self, *, internal_well_known_url: str, server_url: str,
            client_template: str, realm_template: str):

        self.model = OpenIdConnectModel(
            openIdConnectUrl=internal_well_known_url)
        self.scheme_name = 'OpenIdConnect'
        self.auto_error = True
        self.server_url = server_url
        self.client_template = client_template
        self.realm_template = realm_template
        self.kc_clients = {}

    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:

        org = get_org_from_host(request.base_url.hostname)

        if org not in self.kc_clients:

            self.kc_clients[org] = KeycloakOpenID(
                server_url=self.server_url,
                client_id=self.client_template.format(org=org),
                realm_name=self.realm_template.format(org=org))

        authorization: str = request.headers.get("Authorization")

        if not authorization:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Not authenticated")

        try:
            userinfo = self.kc_clients[org].userinfo(
                authorization.replace('Bearer ', ''))

            userinfo['keycloak_realm'] = org
        except KeycloakGetError as e:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail=str(e))

        return userinfo
```

Inspecting `kc_1` service from inside container:

```
[root@e3e5d33ce08b /]# nmap -O localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-04-26 17:01 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000080s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8087/tcp open  simplifymedia
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6.32
OS details: Linux 2.6.32
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.21 seconds
```

and

```
root@e3e5d33ce08b /]# netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:41567        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37927         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:57222        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
Active Bluetooth connections (only servers)
Proto  Destination       Source            State         PSM DCID   SCID      IMTU    OMTU Security
Proto  Destination       Source            State     Channel
[root@e3e5d33ce08b /]#
```

Inspecting domain `auth.bar.local` from `web_1` container:

```
root@0cf70e1cef7f:/usr/src/barz# nmap -p 8087 auth.bar.local
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-04-26 17:02 UTC
Nmap scan report for auth.bar.local (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8087/tcp closed simplifymedia

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.06 seconds
```

It seems that `domainname` is reachable from other containers and from outside, but requests made to port 8087 from outside don't work. I've tried to `ps aux | grep start-dev` and it is running under PID 1. I can even `wget` it inside `kc_1` container and receive a response. I also tried code proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355857/6328506 , but the behavior did not change.

What am I supposed to do to successfully get `http://auth.bar.local:8087/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` using docker compose?

Comment: BTW `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak-x` image was only a preview of Quarkus Keycloak. Now it is released from Keycloak 17+, so I would use `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` instead (minor conf changes may be needed).

Comment: That same seems to occur using keycloak 18

Comment: Note that the `domainname` setting doesn't have anything to do with hostnames or urls; it sets the [NIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) domainname, which was relevant 20 years ago but not so much since then.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `localhost` for `host.docker.internal` and adopting solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026589/6328506 for service `kc` solved the problem. It worth mention that ping/nmap <service_name>, `localhost` and <network_alias> has different effects.